# Constructor argument not inheriting down to children?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, constructor

I am new to php and in particular to oop.  I have this piece of test code that I thought would return:

```
What is the result?8
What is the result?8
```

But, instead I am getting:

```
What is the result?5
What is the result?8
```

The arguments passed into the instance of the class seem not to be getting assigned to x.  I have also tried to `echo $second->x` which returns nothing.

Have I got some code wrong, am I misunderstanding something about inheritance or am I misunderstanding something about `constructors`?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
class First{
    public function __construct($x){
        $this->x = $x;
        echo "What is the result?";
    }
}                                    

class Second extends First{
    public function calculation(){
        $z=5;
        return $x+$z."<br />";
    }
}

class Third extends First{
    public function calculation(){
        $z=5;
        $x=3;
        $y=$x+$z;
        return $y."<br/>";
    }
}

$second = new Second('3');
echo $second->calculation();
$third = new Third('3');
echo $third->calculation();
?>
```

Comment: You need  to use `$this` to access properties: `return $this->x+$z."<br />";`

Comment: Thanks Daan, I actually came to that conclusion soon after posting my question.  Always the way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just little updation over within your `Second` class

```
class Second extends Test{
    public function calculation(){
        $z=5;
        return $this->x+$z."<br />";//$x  should be $this->x
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
What is the result?8
What is the result?8
```

Answer (score 1):

If you override a method, like the constructor in this case, you need to explicitly call the parent class method, like this:

```
class A {
    public function __construct() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function __construct() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        // call parent constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

$b = new B();
```

Output:

```
string(14) "B::__construct"
string(14) "A::__construct"
```